# Checking if a recurrence relation converges or not

Tags: calculus

Consider the recurrence relation $x_{n+1} = \ln{|x_n|}$ where $x_0$ is a real number that is not equal to any multiple of $e$

Will $x_n$ converge to a finite value as $n$ approaches infinity?

Comment: What of $x_0=e$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that condition where $x_0$ is not equal to any multiple of $e$.

Comment: What for $x_0=e^e$ ? And why would you reject $x_0=2e$ ?

Comment: Isn't $2e$ a multiple of $e$? And I am too afraid to ask, but is $e^e$ a multiple of $e$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the recurrence converges, it converges to the root of

$$x=\log(|x|)$$ which is about $x_\infty=-0.5671432904098\cdots$.

But $(\log(|x_\infty|))'=\dfrac1{|x_\infty|}>1$, making convergence impossible.